# How do I append new rows to a PySpark DataFrame guaranteeing a unique ID?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two PySpark DataFrame objects that I wish to concatenate. One of the DataFrames `df_a` has a column `unique_id` derived using `pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id()`. The other DataFrame, `df_b` does not. I want to append the rows of `df_b` to `df_a`, but I need to generate values for the `unique_id` column that do not coincide with any of the values in `df_a.unique_id`.

```
df_a = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "a", 42949672960),
        (2, "b", 85899345920),
        (3, "c", 128849018880)
    ],
    ["number", "letter", "unique_id"]
)

df_b = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (3, "c"),
        (4, "c"),
        (5, "d")
    ],
    ["number", "letter"]
)
df_b = df_b.withColumn("unique_id", F.monotonically_increasing_id())

df = df_a.union(df_b)
df.show()
```

I looked to see if `pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id()` took a parameter enforcing a minimum value, but it does not.

One final thing to note, `df_a` is a massive DataFrame that needs to be appended to regularly. If I needed to reassign unique ids to `df_a` using a function other than `pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id()` to make a potential solution work long-term, I could do so once, but not every time I were to append new data.

Any direction would be appreciated—thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add a constant to `monotonically_increasing_id()`:

```
n = df_a.select(F.max('unique_id').alias('max_n')).first().max_n
df_b = df_b.withColumn("unique_id", F.monotonically_increasing_id() + F.lit(n + 1))
```